# Filter Firebase data in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am retrieving data from Firebase Database using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`, like this,

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Shabee");

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<KejaHelper, KejaViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new 

          FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <KejaHelper, KejaViewHolder>(
                KejaHelper.class,
                R.layout.keja_item,
                KejaViewHolder.class,
                databaseReference
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final KejaViewHolder viewHolder, final KejaHelper model, final int position) {
                final String house_id = getRef(position).getKey();

               // Query qry = databaseReference.child(house_id).orderByChild("place").equalTo(current_location);
                databaseReference.child(house_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                KejaHelper kj = dataSnapshot.getValue(KejaHelper.class);
                                viewHolder.setPrice(kj.getPrice());
                                viewHolder.setPlace(kj.getPlace());
                                viewHolder.setLocation(kj.getLocation());
                                viewHolder.setUid(kj.getUser_id());
                                viewHolder.setImage(getActivity(), kj.getImage());
                                viewHolder.setHouseid(house_id);

                                viewHolder.setUser_id(kj.getUser_id());
                                viewHolder.setFavBtn(house_id);

                               // viewHolder.searchByPrice(house_id,c);
                                countLikes(viewHolder.text, house_id);
                                getComments(house_id,viewHolder.txtComments);


                        }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

So, what the code above does is displaying all the houses present in child `Shabee`

[image: my Database structure]

Now my issue is, I want to display only those houses from one location according to the user's choice i.e. from the same city, I have tried to use `orderByChild()` but I need this line, `final String house_id = getRef(position).getKey();`, which gets all the push keys accordingly. I need filter the houses based on the location preferred by the user.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why doesn't orderbychild work?

Comment: I don't know. The layout doesn't get populated, I can only count the items in the recyclerview but no data in it

Comment: Without orderbychild is it working? Is data getting populated?

Comment: Yes. It gets populated.